# How can i filter pandas endswith mail column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I want to print the ones that match the last indexes of the mails I read from the Excel file, `@gmail.com`. I tried a code like this.

```
import pandas as pd



excelRead = pd.read_excel('mailing.xlsx')
excelRead.dropna(inplace= True)
excelTest = (excelRead['mails'][:-11] == "@gmail.com")
print(excelTest)
```

The output I get is `True` or `False`. I tried a code like this because it says in the sources I researched that I need to import it into a `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd



excelRead = pd.read_excel('mailing.xlsx')
excelRead.dropna(inplace= True)
excelTest = excelRead[(excelRead['mails'][:-11] == "@gmail.com")]
print(excelTest)
```

But this is the `output` I got

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Where am I making mistakes in the executed codes?

Comment: You can also use `excelRead[excelRead['mails'].str.endswith("@gmail.com")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use `excelRead['mails'][:-11]` get last 11 elements of column `mails`, compare with `"@gmail.com"` - get boolean Series with 11 values and then if compare with original DataFrame it raise your error - index of 11 elements is different like index of `excelRead` DataFrame.

---

Correct solution is use `str` for last 9 elements:

```
excelTest = excelRead[excelRead['mails'].str[:-9] == "@gmail.com"]
```

Or:

```
excelTest = excelRead[excelRead['mails'].str.endswith("@gmail.com")]
```